# Multiple Field Update on comma separated values

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am renaming data within columns from names to numbered codes to prepare for importing into a database. This is easy enough if I have single entries within the field, but I'm struggling to update multiple comma separated values. 
For single entries, the below example works fine in field calculator:

```
case when "Enviro" = 'A'
then '118'
when "Enviro" = 'B'
then '119'
when "Enviro" ILIKE '%C%'
then '120'
when "Enviro" ILIKE '%D%'
then '121'
when "Enviro" ILIKE '%E%'
then '122'
when "Enviro" ILIKE '%F%'
then '123'
end
```

However if the "Enviro" field contains both A and B for example (A,B) then the code for 'B' will automatically overwrite any reference to 'A' in the final output. Ideally, I'd want this particular example to read 118,119 in the final version. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not an expert at all but ... appending/concatenating multiple values in one column like u're trying to do doesn't seem to be very "database"-style ... (imho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very elegant, but you can try something like:

```
replace( 
  replace( 
    replace(
      replace("Enviro", 'D', 121),
    'C','120'),
  'B', '119'),
'A', '118')
```

and so on...

Comment: Elegant isn't important just now! Thanks very much, work perfectly.

Comment: @Graham04 You're welcome! If this answer helped you, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer score.